# How to find checkbox in table using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which has only checkbox in first column of each rows. I want to find which checkbox clicked with Jquery (change event). I try this but nothing show up:

```
 $('#table tbody tr td input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                alert("true");//for testing purposes
            }
            alert("false");
        });
```

How to I get clicked element?

```
 <table id="table" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-lg-1">Sıra No.</th>
                            <th class="col-lg-3">İsim/No</th>
                            <th class="col-lg-6">Koordinat Bilgisi</th>
                            <th class="col-lg-2">Mahalle/Kapı</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tableBody">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Edit: My table body is empty in the beginning. I am filling table body after I click a button. And each rows first column has a input element created with plain javascipt.

```
 var indexCheckbox = document.createElement('input');
            indexCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
            indexCheckbox.name = "indexCheckbox";
            indexCheckbox.value = i;
            indexCheckbox.id = "indexCheckbox_" + i;
```

Comment: Not enough known. Sounds like your code runs before elements exist or you have other script errors. Provide a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I think you should put your `js` in `$(document).ready(function(){/*Your code here*/})`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nxjkzs0c/2/ this is demo without css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the checkbox, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked checkbox to #tableBody):

```
$('#tableBody').on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function () {
    if (this.checked) {
       alert("true");//for testing purposes
    }else{
       alert("false");
    }
});
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/pLrk1vrf/